# CKeditor 4: How to check if in inline editing mode and not warn on leave

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am warning my users with an alert when they enter text in the default CKEditor and accidentially might close the window. This functionality is, however, also enabled when editing in the new [inline editing mode](http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline) of CKEditor.

I need to check if we are in "inline mode" to not output the warning. In the [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-inline) I cannot find an isInline() method or alike, so I guess we need a workaround?

I tried to check for the save button `$('.cke_button__savebtn').length==0)` that is only added for inline editing:

```
if(typeof(CKEDITOR) !== 'undefined' && $('.cke_button__savebtn').length==0) {
    var warn_on_leave = false;
    CKEDITOR.on('currentInstance', function() {
        try {
            CKEDITOR.currentInstance.on('key', function() {
                warn_on_leave = true;
            });
        } catch (err) { }
    });
    $("input:submit").click( function() {
        warn_on_leave = false;
        return true;
    });
    // show popup
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        if(warn_on_leave) {
            return 'Your text was not saved. All your text gets lost.';
        }
    });

}
```

But strange enough, it does not work all the time.

Then I thought I could check using JQuery if `contenteditable` exists: `<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">` but my IDs are not constant for the editor field. Mhh.. I could use Jquery to find contenteditable in the entire document...

How would you solve this issue straight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [isInline() method](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-isInline)

you can enumerate the editor instantiated with `CKEDITOR.instances`

```
CKEDITORCUSTOM.closeWarning = function () {
    for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {     
        if (CKEDITOR.instances[i].editable().isInline() === false) {            
            return 'Your text was not saved. All your text gets lost.';
        }
    }
    //return null; do not return anything is better becouse IE become mad
};
window.onbeforeunload = CKEDITORCUSTOM.closeWarning;
```

**Advice:** If you need to get if there are unsaved changes you should use the [change event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) that before CKEditor 4.2 was a plugin:

http://ckeditor.com/addon/onchange

and from 4.2 is embedded:

http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/onChange-event-included-in-CKEditor-4.2

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I just added in the try-catch-block one line:
`try {
 if(!CKEDITOR.currentInstance.editable().isInline()) {
  CKEDITOR.currentInstance.on('key', function() {
   warn_on_leave = true;
  });
 }
} catch (err) { }` which seems to work. If more testing shows problems, I report back. thx.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV :D try also the change event!